# How to prevent Oracle SQL Developer from writing to AppData\Roaming?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any way to prevent Oracle SQL Developer (ver 4.1.5.21) from writing into AppData\Roaming?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? SQL Developer keeps settings in there.

Comment: The directory is stored within the user profile. This space is limited to << 100 MB in my development site.

Comment: I see; well, I don't know whether you can do that or not. Perhaps you could modify History settings in SQL Developer preferences; set number of days to 1 (for example) and use lower number of revisions per file (default is 50, set it to 10). Maybe it'll help keeping available space under control.

Comment: Yes, run it on Linux, then we write the data to your $USERHOME./sqldeveloper directory. You can also use this technique, which will put the data somewhere else http://krisrice.io/2012-05-12-sql-developer-shared-setup-from-any/

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: Sorry but In can't figure out how to configure an windows directory path in the conf-file.

Comment: @jeffthesmith: Thanks for the link. The idea there is not working, but  AddVMOption  -Dide.user.dir= did the job. Thanks for the idea. Still I don't know how to write a full qualified path in conf-file. but no data anymore in roaming profile.That is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Christian4145 leave a comment on Kris' blog with your findings, so the next person can benefit

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a blog post that explains this here :

http://krisrice.io/2012-05-12-sql-developer-shared-setup-from-any/

The crux is to edit sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf

```
AddVMOption -Duser.home=/Users/klrice/Dropbox/sqldev
```

Comment: I don't know why, but in my environment only AddVMOption -Dide.user.dir=/some/path was working.