# How to prevent Oracle SQL Developer from creating the product.conf file in %APPDATA%

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In 2022, the question asked in [how-to-prevent-oracle-sql-developer-from-writing-to-appdata-roaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466116/how-to-prevent-oracle-sql-developer-from-writing-to-appdata-roaming) is still a bit of a problem. While the -Dide.user.dir option does allow you to move the *SQL Developer* directory from %APPDATA%, the application still creates a *sqldeveloper* directory in %APPDATA% that contains a <version>/product.conf file.

What option needs to be added to move this directory as well? I am using version 21.4.3 of SQL Developer. Thanks in advance for any help you all can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convince SQL Developer that it's not actually running on Windows, but is instead on Linux or a Mac.

Otherwise, SQL Developer is designed to do EXACTLY as you describe/observe.

The -Dide.user.dir doesn't let you move those files per se, it more accurately allows you to mirror them somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your response and recommendation.  In theory, that sounds like a great idea, but exactly how do you do that? :-/

Comment: RUn it in a VM/Docker